# What would the adjectival form of "Earl" (the title) be?

Tags: single-word-requests, derivational-morphology

Is there even one?

I know the adjective for "Duke" would be "ducal" ("of, like or relating to a Duke or dukedom"). But I can't find a good version of the word for an Earl.

Any thoughts?

Sorry if this is not the appropriate venue for this question, but thought I would give it a shot.

Comment: You might use "comital" as it is the adjective form of "count". "Count" is equivalent to the English "earl", "earl" surviving as a title after the Norman Conquest as the historic title name. "Countess" is used in English as the feminine form of "earl", as there seems to be no native historic equivalent..

Comment: Obviously, "early" would be the adverb.

Comment: @HotLicks: Either you're taking the joke one step too far, or you've fallen into the trap of thinking that all "-ly" words are adverbs.  Words like "chilly", "curly", "kingly" and "pearly" are adjectives.  The question is asking for an adjective, and, even in its real meaning, "early" can be an adjective (although it can also be an adverb).

Comment: @Scott - [It's a joke, son!](https://youtu.be/KTwnwbG9YLE)

Comment: @HotLicks: I know that it's *meant* to be a joke; when I saw the question, I also thought of making a joke about "early". My point is that it's a poorly executed joke, and I find it marvelously ironic that you linked to a video of somebody trying to construct a joke, and getting only 70% of the way there.    :-)    ⁠

Comment: @Scott - "It's a joke, son!" is the premier catchphrase of the cartoon character Foghorn Leghorn.  Unfortunately, I was unable to locate a better video of him using this, but it occurred in just about every episode of his cartoons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the correct word would be **comital**, as *earl* is the English equivalent of a continental *count*.